# jQuery Mobile - Swipe Slider for Navbar navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, navigation, slider

Using jQuery mobile, how is it possible to add a swipe/slider into the footer or header navigation.

So where you have a data-role="navbar" with all the icons, how is it possible to add in a slider where you can swipe or press an arrow left/right to show more icons on the menu?

[I have found this working example:](http://themeforest.net/item/rodin-jquery-mobile-web-theme/2901378)

How would I do this?

Comment: Essentially, you'd want to build the entire bar and slide it left and right with CSS. This can be done through the `slide` event. See more: [JQM Events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html). I will see if I can find a more full example or make one. If you have any example code of what you've tried. Please edit and add that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to do it, roughly, As it uses JQM code, you can ThemeRoll it just fine. Working test example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yMpcE/

Still working out the Swipe to the right action.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="header">
            <h2>Test Scroll Bar</h2>
            <div id="scrollBar" class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Test Page</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-fullscreen="false">
            <div data-role="navbar">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#scrollBar {
    width: 840px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    var scrollBarLinks = {
        0: '#home',
        1: '#link2',
        2: '#link3',
        3: '#link4',
        4: '#link5',
        5: '#link6',
        6: '#link7',
        7: '#link8',
        8: '#link9',
        9: '#link10',
        10: '#link11',
        11: '#link12'
    };
    var scrollBarText = {
        0: 'Home',
        1: 'Link 2',
        2: 'Link 3',
        3: 'Link 4',
        4: 'Link 5',
        5: 'Link 6',
        6: 'Link 7',
        7: 'Link 8',
        8: 'Link 9',
        9: 'Link 10',
        10: 'Link 11',
        11: 'Link 12'
    };
    var scrollBarIcons = {
        0: 'home',
        1: 'star',
        2: 'star',
        3: 'star',
        4: 'star',
        5: 'star',
        6: 'star',
        7: 'star',
        8: 'star',
        9: 'star',
        10: 'star',
        11: 'star'
    };

    var numLinksShown = 6;
    var scrollCursor = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < numLinksShown; i++) {
        $("<a>", {
            'href': scrollBarLinks[i],
            'id': 'scrollBarBtn-' + i,
            'data-role': 'button',
            'data-inline': true,
            'data-icon': scrollBarIcons[i],
            'data-iconpos': 'right',
            'text': scrollBarText[i]
        }).appendTo("#scrollBar").button();
    }

    $("#scrollBar").swiperight(function() {
        if (scrollCursor == 0) {
            alert("Can't slide to the right. 0");
            return false;
        }
        $("#scrollBar > a:last").remove();
        scrollCursor--;
        $("<a>", {
            'href': scrollBarLinks[scrollCursor],
            'id': 'scrollBarBtn-' + (scrollCursor),
            'data-role': 'button',
            'data-inline': true,
            'data-icon': scrollBarIcons[scrollCursor],
            'data-iconpos': 'right',
            'text': scrollBarText[scrollCursor]
        }).appendTo("#scrollBar").button();
    });

    $("#scrollBar").swipeleft(function() {
        if (scrollCursor == scrollBarLinks.length) {
            alert("Can't slide to the left. " + scrollBarLinks.length);
            return false;
        }
        $("#scrollBar > a:first").remove();
        var nextBtn = scrollCursor + numLinksShown;
        scrollCursor++;
        $("<a>", {
            'href': scrollBarLinks[nextBtn],
            'id': 'scrollBarBtn-' + (nextBtn),
            'data-role': 'button',
            'data-inline': true,
            'data-icon': scrollBarIcons[nextBtn],
            'data-iconpos': 'right',
            'text': scrollBarText[nextBtn]
        }).appendTo("#scrollBar").button();
    });
});
```

As you can see, you can make it as long as you want. Swiping will move it over one button at a time in this example. I am sure you can have be more responsive to a short swipe versus a long swipe, or you can have it move half the number shown. You can use your own icons and style the buttons to be a specific size or look.